# C++ Return either a string or int without auto

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I am writing an SQL controller with a Column class. The Column class has properties

1. Name (string)
2. Type (enum list)
3. Index (in row)
4. Value

But values can be strings or ints. In *reality*, in sqlite anyway, all values are returned as `char` arrays. But in the end I want the user to be able to do something like

```
Column column = row->GetColumn(1);
value = column->GetValue();
```

Now I don't have access to `auto` so I'm not even sure how to handle this on any level, neither from the caller (how do they necessarily know what the value type is?) and from the Column class.

Comment: The user of your column class will have to query the class for the type via a method you create, something like `GetValueType`.

Comment: Have `GetValue()` return a `std::variant` (or `boost::variant` if you are using a pre-C++17 compiler) that is populated with the correct data based on the actual SQL type. Then the caller can extract data from the `variant` based on what is actually stored in it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this seems to be the correct solution, so why don't you write it up and collect your internet points?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso It still requires the user to know the type the column will store. They can obviously call `holds_alternative`, but if the variant template changes in the future a lot of the code will break since ICU_ doesn't have access to auto. The best solution, in my opinion, would be to store the type internally in the column and have `getTYPEValue()` methods.

Comment: @Kyle There are a finite number of types an SQL value can be. A `variant` can be defined to hold all of the available types, and some of those types (like char arrays, different sized integers, etc) can be abstracted into more generic types to reduce the number of types the `variant` needs to deal with (ie, `char`..`short`..`int` -> `int`, `char[]`..`varchar` -> `std::string`, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point.

Answer (score 4):

Have `GetValue()` return a `std::variant` (or `boost::variant` if you are using a pre-C++17 compiler) that is populated with the correct data based on the actual SQL type. Then the caller can extract data from the variant based on what is actually stored in it:

```
typedef std::variant<std::monostate, int, std::string, and_so_on...> SQLValue;
...

SQLValue value = column->GetValue();

if (std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>(value))
{
    // you can use this for null data...
}
else if (std::holds_alternative<int>(value))
{
    int ivalue = std::get<int>(value);
    ...
}
else if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(value))
{
    std::string svalue = std::get<std::string>(value);
    ...
}
else ...
```

Alternatively:

```
SQLValue value = column->GetValue();

if (std::get_if<std::monostate>(&value))
{
    // you can use this for null data...
}
else if (int *p_ivalue = std::get_if<int>(&value))
{
    int ivalue = *p_ivalue;
    ...
}
else if (std::string *p_svalue = std::get_if<std::string>(&value))
{
    std::string svalue = *p_svalue;
    ...
}
else ...
```

Alternatively:

```
SQLValue value = column->GetValue();

switch (value.index())
{
    case 0:
    {
        // you can use this for null data...
        break;
    }

    case 1:
    {
        int ivalue = get:::get<1>(value);
        ...
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        std::string svalue = std::get<2>(&value);
        ...
        break;
    }

    case ...
}
```